# Django-rest-framework 'Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce, '

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-timezone

I am using django-rest-framework and trying to use my timezone date as the default for **Date** field but I am unable to do so. For **DateTime** field setting the **default=timezone.now** works perfectly but for **Date** field it gives the error in serialization.

**'Expected a `date`, but got a `datetime`. Refusing to coerce'**

`time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`
This Works

`date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)`
But this does not work

`date = models.DateField(default=timezone.datetime.today)`
And even this doesn't work.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: @mmla I did a work around by changing all date fields to datetime fields and getting only date part where needed and ignoring time part

Comment: Seeing as this was incorrectly marked as duplicate, I can't leave an answer, but for anyone who also had this error I had the following field in my models:
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
I think 'date' might be a reserved field title and changing that to 
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
fixed it for me. (Worked on my machine but deploying to a postgresql db on webfaction introduced it)